# Visualforce Error , unexpected token list

Tags: apex, visualforce

How can I resolve this issue?

**Error**

> Visualforce Error , unexpected token list

**Page**

```
<apex:page controller="CustomPagination">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Custom Pagination of Lead List">
            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!AllLead}" var="cl" >
                <apex:column value="{!cl.firstName}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!cl.lastName}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!cl.company}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!cl.phone}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!cl.status}"/>
            </apex:pageblockTable>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandbutton value="First Page" action="{!first}"/> 
                <apex:commandbutton value="<< Previous" action="{!previous}"/> 
                <apex:commandbutton value="List" action="{!list}"/> 
                <apex:commandbutton value="Next >>" action="{!Next}"/>
                <apex:commandbutton value="Last Page" action="{!last}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class CustomPagination{
    integer counter;

        public void previous(){
            if(counter>10) counter=counter-10;
            else counter=0;
        }

        public void next(){
            counter=counter+10;
        }

        public list<lead> getAllLead(){
        list<lead> AllLead=[select id, firstName, lastName, company, phone, status from lead limit 15 offset:counter];
        return AllLead;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have several bindings which correspond to nothing on your controller:

- `first`
- `last`
- `list`

For each of these, you must define a method. I suggest you just expose a `StandardSetController`. There's little benefit to writing your own pagination here.

```
public with sharing class MyController
{
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController controller { get; private set; }
    public MyController()
    {
        controller = new ApexPages.StandardSetController([
            SELECT ... FROM Lead
        ]);
        controller.setPageSize(15);
    }
}
```

Then in your markup, you just bind to `controller` instead:

- `<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!controller.records}" var="lead" />`
- `<apex:commandButton value="First Page" action="{!controller.first}" />`
- `<apex:commandButton value="<<" action="{!controller.previous}" />`
- `<apex:commandButton value="List" action="{!controller.list}" />`
- `<apex:commandButton value=">>" action="{!controller.next}" />`
- `<apex:commandButton value="Last Page" action="{!controller.last}" />`

Another benefit is that you can add `disabled` properties for `next` and `previous` if those options should not be available:

```
<apex:commandButton value="<<"
                    action="{!controller.previous}"
                    disabled="{!NOT(controller.hasPrevious)}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

`<apex:commandbutton value="List" action="{!list}"/>` is not pointing to a method or variable that exists. That is your problem.

PS: You might want to consider using Standard Set Controllers for your use-case. Read [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm).

Comment: Not the only missing method.